# Riemann Integrals - Proving integrability

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-sum, riemann-integration

Here is my question:

> Let $g(x)$ be the function defined on $[0, 2]$ such that $g(x) = 1$
>   for $0 ≤ x ≤ 1$ and $g(x) = 2$ for $1 < x ≤ 2$. Use the definition of
>   the Riemann Integral to show that $g(x)$ is Riemann Integrable over
>   the interval $[0, 2]$.

Also, is it necessary that the upper and lower Riemann sums converge to the same value? In an **unrelated question**, I evaluated an infinite sum corresponding to both limits and proved that they were not equal. By this fact alone, can I say that the said function was not Riemann Integrable?

Comment: You must have made a mistake, the two riemann sums should be equal.  And it does matter, they need to be equal for it to be reimann integrable.

Comment: Try this partition: $\{0,1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon,2\}$ and let $\epsilon$ go to zero.

Comment: That was a separate question. I was trying to prove that it was not integrable. If that is the case, I think I succeeded.

Comment: If you have two sequences of subdivisions with granularity converging to zero but giving different limits in the Riemann sums, then the function is not Riemann-integrable. The range of values attainable via Riemann sums of any construction and a given granularity has to have a diameter that shrinks to zero as the granularity shrinks to zero.

Comment: @user282934 You have it wrong, this function *is* Riemann integrable.

Comment: @user282934 A bounded function that is continuous at all but a finite number of points is always Riemann integrable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various definitions of Riemann integrability around. The simplest is the following: A function $f:\>[a,b]\to{\mathbb R}$ (or $\to{\mathbb R}^n$) is *Riemann integrable* over $[a,b]$ if it passes the following test: For any $\epsilon>0$ there are a  partition
$$T:\quad a=t_0<t_1<\ldots<t_N=b$$
and estimates
$$|f(y)-f(x)|\leq\Delta_k\qquad(t_{k-1}\leq t\leq t_k)$$
such that
$$D:=\sum_{k=1}^N \Delta_k\>(t_k-t_{k-1})<\epsilon\ .$$
For your $g$ take the partition
$$t_0=0,\quad t_1=1-{\epsilon\over3},\quad t_2=1+{\epsilon\over3},\quad t_3=2$$
and obtain
$$D={2\over3}\epsilon\ .$$

Comment: What is $A$ ?  ${}$

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD: ($A$ was a variable for an arbitrary set.) See my edit. It's even simpler now.

Answer (score 2):

For $n>2,$ let $P_n = \{0,1-1/n,1+1/n,2\}.$ Then $$U(f,P_n) - L(f,P_b) = (1-1)(1-1/n) + (2-1)\frac{2}{n} + (2-2)(1-1/2n) = \frac{2}{n}.$$ Thus $U(f,P_n) - L(f,P_b)\to 0.$ This implies $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,2].$