# Checking my attempt in proving the function is Riemann Integrable.

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

It was familiar to me to deal with continuous functions in proving Riemann integrability, so I wanna show my work in solving [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1535659/riemann-integrals-proving-integrability?rq=1) (maybe in a messy way) and I'm waiting for any advice or hint.

I chose $\delta_{x_i}= \frac{1}{n}$.

We have $m_i= 1$,   $\forall$ $i$.

$  M_i =
  \begin{cases}
    1      & \quad \text{if }  \text{ $x_i$ doesn't belong to a subinterval containing 1}\\
    2  & \quad \text{if }  \text{ $x_i$ belongs to a subinterval containing 1}\\
  \end{cases}$

So $L(f,P)= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n 1$ $=1$.

$U(f,P)= \frac{1}{n}.2 + \frac{1}{n}.2 +  \sum_{i=1}^{n-2} 1$ $= \frac{n-1}{n} + \frac{4}{n}$.

So we have $|U(f,P)- L(f,P)|$ $= \frac{n-1}{n} + \frac{4}{n} - 1$ $\longrightarrow 0$. Therefore, the function is Riemann integrable.

I feel that I'm catching the idea but not dealing well with it. Please guide me the right track and the right way of writing.

Thanks!

Comment: You only need to consider partitions into three subintervals, something like $P_n=\{0,1-1/n,1+1/n,2\}.$ You're overthinking this a bit.

Comment: And my overthinking led me to a wrong way? But please how did you know that I need only 3 partitions.?

Comment: I thought choosing n subintervals with equal lengths is better :(